# How to run two Postdoctoral fellowships at the same time?

Tags: postdocs, funding

I have recently applied for two different Postdoctoral fellowships in the same host group and I got both of them. My host is very happy and suggests me to run both of them at the same time. However, there are some administration details that are not clear to me at all. For example, will the fellowship foundation be happy to known that I will be running another fellowship at the same time?

My current plan is to ask one of the foundation (I) to fund a technician and I could still ask the foundation II to support my own salary. In this case, I think I will definitely need to negotiate with foundation I because the change of personnel. Question is that how should I inform foundation II? In fact nothing is changed here, I feel like I am looking for troubles if I simply inform them (foundation II) that I got another funding to support a technician.

Your ideas/experiences about how to handle this situation will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you talking about hiring two post docs on two different fellowships or about being a post doc and working on two different fellowships?

Comment: @StrongBad as far as I understood it's the second and AFAIK it's most probably forbidden by the conditions under which the fellowship is granted (there may be exceptions, though).

Comment: Do you still have the application package? Usually it would list requirements in detail, including if you can be supported by dual funding and how much time they are paying you for. In my opinion, if both are full-time funding, the plan sounds very greedy and selfish; the money could have been used to support two post-docs. In any case, I wish you good luck.

Comment: _My host is very happy and suggests me to run both of them at the same time._ — This seems strange to me. Why would your host be "very happy" about this arrangement?

Comment: Could you explain in more detail what it would mean to have "two different Postdoctoral fellowships in the same host group"?  Do you mean that you would have two different (but somehow overlapping) *positions* or do you mean that you would have one soft-money position which would be funded by two different sources?  If it's the latter, the answer seems easy: you definitely need to inform both different sources and ask if they are okay with the double funding.  (I would expect them not to be.)

Comment: I would be very careful with the regulations. Any kind of funds generally explicitly or implicitly assume a set amount of minimum hours you put in the research, and post-doc fellowships generally assume full time commitments. Therefore they often explicitly eg. forbid to carry any other job.

Comment: @StrongBad@Pete L. Clark@Greg Thank you very much for your kind answers/questions. Please refer to Dylan Richard Muir's answer. I didn't explain it clearly enough in my questions, but the scopes of the two foundations are different. Otherwise it wouldn't be possible.

Comment: Hope neither foundation finds out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally foundations "request" that you inform them if you receive extra funding for the same budget. They probably expect that you apply to several foundations simultaneously. However, if you negotiate with foundation I to change the scope of the funding (such that it doesn't go towards your salary, which is presumably already covered by foundation II), then I think you're in the clear.

Alternatively, if foundation II didn't fund your full budget, then you could accept part of the funds from foundation I to cover the remaining costs, then inform both foundations of the arrangement. That should also be uncontroversial.